# Swift Realm - one to many filter query

Tags: swift, realm

```
class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    let owners = List<Owner>()
}
```

Here, dogs can belong to more than one owner. So, say I have a particular Owner object. How can I set up a query to get all dogs that have that owner in their `owners` list?

```
func allDogsFor(owner: Owner) -> [Dog]? {
    let query = realm.objects(Owner.self).filter???
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [inverse relationship](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships). The way it works (from docs):

> With linking objects properties, you can obtain all objects that link
>   to a given object from a specific property. A `Dog` object can have a
>   property named owners that contains all of the `Person` objects that
>   have this exact `Dog` object in their dogs property. Make the owners
>   property of type `LinkingObjects` and then specifying the relationship
>   that it has with the `Person` object.

where `Person` it's your `Owner`.

I recommend you rewrite little bit your code, because it makes more sense when the `owner` has `dogs`. Basic example could be:

```
final class Owner: Object {
    let dogs = List<Dog>()
}

final class Dog: Object {
    let owners = LinkingObjects(fromType: Owner.self, property: "dogs")
}

let dogsForOwner = owner.dogs
let ownersOfADog = dog.owners
```

Comment: This isn't addressing the question of how to query all of the dogs for a specific owner. Can you update the answer to address that question?

Comment: Hi @Jay, thanks for the comment! I strongly believe that @tariq has an architecture issue and i pointed it out. As for main question, i also suggested to use the `LinkingObjects` which is correct for my solution.

Comment: No disagreement here there may be room for architecture improvement. However, we have a few cases where we have objects that are stored in lists where we don't care about the inverse relationship so LinkingObjects is not needed; that's why I stated that the first part of my answer was an answer to that specific question. Overall, LinkingObjects is usually best practice and based on the OP's followup questions, probably a good idea ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to your specific question.

Using the same Dog class you have shown in the question, you are asking how to query the Dogs' owners property for a specific owner and you want to return all of the dogs that have that owner.

There are a couple of ways to go about it so here's one way:

Suppose you have an owner with the last_name of Smith - first we want to get that specific owner object and then query all of the Dog Lists for it

```
let ownerResults = realm.objects(OwnerClass.self).filter("last_name == 'Smith'")
if let smithOwner = ownerResults.first {
    let dogResults = realm.objects(DogClass.self).filter("ANY owners == %@", smithOwner)
    for dog in dogResults {
        print(dog.dog_name)
    }
}
```

And then a second option (as mentioned in another answer) is to use LinkingObjects. Linking objects 'automatically' create a link (inverse relationship) back to another object.

So take a look at these classes

```
class OwnerClass: Object {
   let dogList = List<DogClass>()
}
```

and

```
class DogClass: Object {
   let owners = LinkingObjects(fromType: OwnerClass.self, property: "dogList")
}
```

the cool thing here is that when we create a dog class and add it to the owner

```
let owner = OwnerClass()
owner.dogList.append(aDog)
```

then write it to realm

```
let realm = try Realm()

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(owner)
}
```

that dog is also added to realm and the link established.

To revisit the question;

> say I have a particular Owner object. How can I set up a query to get
>   all dogs that have that owner in their owners list

To re-state that

> I want to know all the dogs that are in a particular owners dogList

In this scenario, you don't need a query. An owner has dogs any dogs added to an owner are part of that owners dogsList

```
let ownerResults = realm.objects(PersonClass.self).filter("last_name == 'Smith'")
if let smithOwner = ownerResults.first {

    let smithsDogs = smithOwner.dogs //no query! this is all
                                     //  of the dogs that have smith as an owner
    for dog in smithsDogs {
        print(dog.dog_name)
    }
}
```

In fact, we don't even need a LinkingObjects property in each dog since if we add those dogs to an owner

```
owner.dogList.append(objectsIn: [dog0, dog1, dog2])
```

it's pretty clear there are three dogs in that owners dogList. The LinkingObjects however, will allow us to traverse back to the owner from each dog.

Comment: This is really great. LinkingObjects makes sense. However, it's not clear to me, when I'm creating a dog, how to set its owners property. I have an array of 3 owners for example, but dog.owners = selectedOwners gives the error "Cannot assign value of type '[Owner]' to type 'LinkingObjects<Owner>"

Comment: Hi, @tariq. You shouldn't manually set `LinkingObjects` property, because realm handle this relationship.

Comment: @tariq Flip your thinking around, and take a look at the code in the answer starting with *the cool thing here*.... You don't create a dog and set it's owners property. You create the dog, add it to the owners Dogs list and the LinkingObjects property of the dog class is automatically updated. You don't need to do anything else. Pretty slick, huh.